# How to Get WSFC Name Using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, clustering

I know how to get the name of the current node, but is there a simple T-SQL query to use to get the Windows Server Failover Cluster name that the clustered instance is part of?

The SQL Server version is 2014 and the OS is Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Molenpad, you shall get the WSFC details through below mention TSQL query.

```
select * from master.sys.dm_hadr_cluster;
Go
```

Here `cluster_name` is the Name of the `WSFC` cluster that hosts the instances of SQL Server that are enabled for Always On availability groups.

I am also attaching the screen shot.
[image]

**Note:** I have highlighted the WSFC name due to my Prod server.

for your ref [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-cluster-transact-sql)

Comment: This is great. Just adding a note that,  this is also work for Failover Cluster Instances (FCI) starting SQL 2014 edition.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, Yes, As from microsoft there is tips " Beginning in SQL Server 2014, this dynamic management view supports Always On Failover Cluster Instances in addition to Always On Availability Groups".